# Can another client app close TCP connection which a crashed client app opened with a server?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

Consider the following sequence:

1. Client app (web browser) opens several TCP connections to different web servers;
2. Ethernet cable then becomes disconnected;
3. Client app is then closed;
4. Ethernet cable remains disconnected for a few hours;
5. Ethernet cable is reconnected;
6. I see "TCP keep-alive" packets (every 60 seconds, for hours) from a few of the servers to which the long-closed client app had connected!

Normally, when an app is closing, the app would initiate the closure of each open socket, and the TCP layer would then attempt to send a FIN packet to each remote endpoint.  If it is physically possible to send the FIN packet, and such sending actually happens, then the local endpoint goes from the ESTABLISHED state to the FINWAIT_1 state (and awaits receiving an ACK from the remote endpoint, etc.).  But, if the physical link is broken, then the TCP local endpoint can't send that FIN, and the server still assumes the TCP connection still exists (and the client-side call to the "close" function would block indefinitely until the physical link was reestablished, assuming the socket were set to blocking mode, right?).

In any case, upon reconnecting the Ethernet cable after some time with all conventional networked apps (e.g., web browsers) long closed, I am receiving "TCP Keep-Alive" packets from three separate web servers at precisely 60-second intervals for HOURS!

Wireshark shows the local port numbers to which these `TCP Keep-Alive` packets are being sent, but neither `TCPView` nor `netstat -abno` show those local port numbers being used by any application.  Looking at the "TCP/IP" property of every single running process using Process Explorer also does not show any matching port numbers.  I don't think the ports are being held because of a zombie "process record" (of, say, the web browser process) due to any ongoing child process (e.g., plugin app), but I'm not sure if my observations with TCPView/netstat/Process Explorer were sufficient to rule out this possibility.

Given the identities of the remote web servers (e.g., Akamai servers), I believe the connections were established by "recent" use of a web browser.  But, these keep-alives keep coming from those three web servers, even though the browser had been closed, and the physical link had been broken for hours.

If the connections appeared in `TCPView`, I could simply select them and manually close them.  However, the client-side TCP endpoints seem long gone.

Meanwhile, I am baffled why the servers are retrying so many times to get a reply to their keep-alive packets.

TCP keep-alive behavior is typically controlled by three parameters: \

(1) Time to wait until the next "burst" or "probe" attempts;

(2) Time interval between sending each keep-alive packet during a single "probe" attempt;

(3) The maximum number of "probe" attempts before the "burst" is considered a failure (and the TCP connection is consequently considered permanently broken).

For the TCP keep-alive packets I am seeing from the three different servers, the time interval between "probe" retries is exactly 60 seconds.  But, it seems like the maximum number of "probe" retries is infinite, which seems like a really bad choice for any server!

Although I am curious about how this relentless stream of keep-alives was created and sustained, I am more immediately interested in how I might use a client-side application to force the server-side endpoints to close, given that there aren't existing local TCP endpoints receiving those keep-alive packets.

My rough idea is to create an app which creates a TCP-mode socket, binds (with port-number reuse allowed) to the port number to which the incoming keep-alives are directed, and then call "open" followed by "close", hoping that the server endpoint will make the TCP state transitions to reach the closed state one way or another!  Another way might be to create a raw-mode socket, and receive the TCP keep-alive packet (which is just an ACK), and then form and send an appropriate FIN packet (with proper sequence number, etc., to pick up where the long-terminated client app evidently left off), and then receive an ACK and FIN before sending the final ACK.

One final note -- and I *know* there will be eye-rolling and ridicule: the working environment here is Windows XP SP3 running in VirtualBox on Windows 7!  So, I'd prefer code or an open-source app which could achieve the goal (closing half-open TCP connection) within Windows XP SP3.  Sure, I could restart the snapshot, which *might* close the connections -- but I am more interested in learning how to get more information about the state of network connections, and what I can do to handle this kind of TCP state problem.

Comment: I believe TCP does not even send any keep alive packets by default. The application has to enable this first. Are you sure these are keep alive packets?

Comment: @usr Yes, Wireshark clearly indicated "TCP keep-alive" for the periodic ACK packets I received.  And, yes, it would require the server to explicitly set the socket option to enable TCP keep-alive behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I succeeded in provoking the closing of each apparent half-open TCP connection by writing a simple program (full code appears below) which binds a local socket to the port to which the server believes it is already connected, attempts to establish a new connection, and then closes the connection.

(Note: If the connection succeeds, I make an HTTP GET request, just because the phantom TCP keep-alives in my case are apparently originating from plain HTTP servers, and I was wondering what response I might get back.  I think the "send" and "recv" calls could be removed without affecting the ability of the code to achieve the desired result.)

In the following code, the **src_port_num** variable represents the client-side port number (currently unused) to which the server is sending "TCP keep-alive" packets, and **dst_ip_cstr** is the IP address of the server (e.g., an Akamai web server), and **dst_port_num** is the port number (which, in my situation, happens to be a plain HTTP server at port 80).

**CAUTION!**  By sharing this code I do not mean to imply that its theory of operation can be rigorously explained by an understanding of the TCP protocol specification.  I just guessed that claiming an abandoned local port to which a remote endpoint is sending TCP keep-alive packets, and attempting to establish a new connection to that very same remote endpoint, would, one way or another, prod the remote endpoint to close the stale half-open connection -- *and it happened to work for me*.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

void main()
{
  // Local IP and port number
  char * src_ip_cstr  = "10.0.2.15";
  int    src_port_num = 4805;

  // Remote IP and port number
  char * dst_ip_cstr  = "23.215.100.98";
  int    dst_port_num = 80;

  int res = 0;
  WSADATA wsadata;
  res = WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2,2), (&(wsadata)) );
  if (0 != res) { printf("WSAStartup() FAIL\n"); return; }

  printf( "\nSRC IP:%-16s Port:%d\nDST IP:%-16s Port:%d\n\n",
  src_ip_cstr, src_port_num, dst_ip_cstr, dst_port_num );

  sockaddr_in src;
  memset( (void*)&src, 0, sizeof(src) );
  src.sin_family           = AF_INET;
  src.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr( src_ip_cstr );
  src.sin_port             = htons( src_port_num );

  sockaddr_in dst;
  memset( (void*)&dst, 0, sizeof(dst) );
  dst.sin_family           = AF_INET;
  dst.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr( dst_ip_cstr );
  dst.sin_port             = htons( dst_port_num );

  int s = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP );
  if ((-1) == s) { printf("socket() FAIL\n"); return; }

  int val = 1;
  res = setsockopt( s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 
  (const char*)&val, sizeof(val) );
  if (0 != res) { printf("setsockopt() FAIL\n"); return; }

  res = bind( s, (sockaddr*)&src, sizeof(src) );
  if ((-1) == res) { printf("bind() FAIL\n"); return; }

  res = connect( s, (sockaddr*)&dst, sizeof(dst) );
  if ((-1) == res) { printf("connect() FAIL\n"); return; }

  char req[1024];
  sprintf( req, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nAccept: text/html\r\n"
  "Accept-Language: en-us,en\r\nAccept-Charset: US-ASCII\r\n\r\n", 
  dst_ip_cstr );
  printf("REQUEST:\n================\n%s\n================\n\n", req );

  res = send( s, (char*)&req, strlen(req), 0 );
  if ((-1) == res) { printf("send() FAIL\n"); return; }

  const int REPLY_SIZE = 4096;
  char reply[REPLY_SIZE];
  memset( (void*)&reply, 0, REPLY_SIZE );
  res = recv( s, (char*)&reply, REPLY_SIZE, 0 );
  if ((-1) == res) { printf("recv() FAIL\n"); return; }
  printf("REPLY:\n================\n%s\n================\n\n", reply );

  res = shutdown( s, SD_BOTH );
  res = closesocket( s );

  res = WSACleanup();
}
```

**HILARIOUS / SHAMEFUL / FASCINATING DISCLOSURES**

As I mentioned in my original question, I observed these "TCP keep-alive" packets with Wireshark within VirtualBox running Windows XP SP3, where the host OS was Windows 7.

When I woke up this morning and looked at the phenomenon again with a cup of coffee and fresh eyes, with the "TCP keep-alive" packets still appearing every 60 seconds even after 24 hours, I made a hilarious discovery: These packets continued to arrive from the three different IP addresses, precisely at 60-second intervals (but staggered for the three IPs), *even when I disconnected the Ethernet cable from the Internet*!  My mind was blown!

So, although the three IP addresses did correspond to real-world web servers to which my web browser connected long ago, the TCP keep-alive packets were clearly originating from some local software component.

This revelation, as shocking as it was, did not change my thinking about the situation: from my client-side software perspective, there were "server-side" half-open TCP connections that I wanted to provoke to closing.

Within VirtualBox, choosing **"Devices" -> "Network" -> "Connect Network Adapter"** toggles the virtual network adapter on or off, as if a virtual Ethernet cable were connected or disconnected.  Toggling to a disconnected state caused the phantom TCP keep-alive packets to stop arriving to Wireshark.  Subsequently toggling to a connected state caused the TCP keep-alive packets to resume arriving in Wireshark.

Anyway, I sometimes needed to run the code above TWICE to succeed in closing the half-open connection.  When running the code a first time, Wireshark would show a packet with an annotation "[TCP ACKed unseen segment]", which is just the kind of TCP gas-lighting confusion I hoped to create, haha!  Because the new client endpoint is unexpected by the remote endpoint, the call to "connect" hangs for maybe 30 seconds before failing.  For a couple of the zombie/phantom half-open connections, running the program just once was enough to also cause an RST packet.

I needed to modify the program repeatedly to change the combination of local port number, remote IP, and remote port number, to match each phantom TCP keep-alive packet I observed in Wireshark.  (I leave implementing user-friendly command-line parameters to the dear reader (that's you!).)  After a few rounds of modifying and running the program, all zombie keep-alive packets were stopped.  "Silence of the Packets", one might say.

**EPILOGUE**

*[In tuxedo, martini glass in hand, gazing wistfully at the ocean from the deck of a yacht, in the company of fellow hackers]* "I never did figure out where those zombie packets came from...  Was it the 'VirtualBox Host-Only Network' virtual Ethernet adapter?  Only the Oracle knows!"

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you need to do to close the remote socket, it is already built into the TCP protocol. If the system receives TCP packets which don't create a new connection (i.e. have SYN set) and don't belong to any established connection, it will reply with a RST packet. This way the peer will know that the endpoint is no longer there and abandon the connection.